# how to Continous loop collection without concurrentmodificationexception

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentmodification

Please read the text carefully, the title isn't so good, but i couldn't think something easier to describe the problem.

This is a theorical problem, i will use java to demonstrate but the solution i need is more like a design pattern so it could be thougth for any language.

> A program has 2 threads:
>   thread A - interacts with user, who can add or remove items to a set
>   thread B - continously iterate over a Set performing tasks over its items

How can i perform this scenario without having `ConcurrentModificationException` ?

```
final Set<String> set = new HashSet();

//A
new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
while(true){

//user adds or remove items to set

}
}
}).start();


new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
while(true){

for(String s : set){
//do stuff
}

}
}
}).start();
```

This is a very commum scenario there shall be a design pattern to handle it

Comment: maybe a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CopyOnWriteArraySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html)

For example

`Set<Integer> threadSafeSet = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();`

The above set can now be accessed from any thread without `ConcurrentModificationException`s. But its not realtime i.e the set can change and this wont be reflected in an ongoing iteration. This a drawback for the benefit of a thread safe iterator